# uv__queue_done: Assertion `((req->loop)->active_reqs.count > 0)' failed?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-modules, nodejs-server

Recently we are testing Node.js with C++ addon for request processing scalability.

Please follow the below steps for more understanding:

1. We registered a callback function of the Node.js in C++ addon..which is called (callback) from the C++ addon whenever a request comes in.
2. Initial request will hit C++ addon first then it will hit the Node.js callback function.
3. However, if we put a load of requests more than an hour or so ..it crashes with the error I provided above.

Please look at the below code. The initial call is `sendData`:

```
    struct Work {
      int status;
      uv_work_t request;
      string data;
      Persistent<Function> callback;
    };

    static void WorkAsync(uv_work_t *req) {
         //Work *work = static_cast<Work *>(req->data);
    }

    static void WorkAsyncComplete(uv_work_t *req, int status) {
       Isolate * isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
       v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate); // Required for Node 4.x

       Work *work = static_cast<Work *>(req->data);

       Handle<Value> argv[1];
       argv[0] = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, work->data.c_str());

       Local<Function>::New(isolate, m_work->callback)->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
   }
   void sendData(std::string str) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
      m_work->data = str;
      uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(),&m_work->request, WorkAsync, WorkAsyncComplete);
}
```

Thanks